# SQL Server 2005 - Multiple lookup for values from single table in one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help, please see below table structure:

```
Table: MainData (see fields below)

ID  TypeId  TypeName
0   0   MAIN
1   4   Test1
2   4   Test2
3   4   Test3
4   4   Test4
7   7   File1
8   7   File2
9   7   File3
10  7   File4
14  8   Database1
15  8   Datebase2
16  8   Database3
17  8   Database4
```

See query below now with which i'm strugling

Insert into temptable (Field1, Field2, Field3) Values (Test1, File4, Database3)

Test1, File4, Database3 - I have got these as string values passed to function, now to have to get their ID's which need to be insert into temptable

So then below query should become

Insert into temptable (Field1, Field2, Field3) Values (1, 10, 16)

```
1 - Test1
10 - File4
16 - Database3
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into temptable
    select (select id from Maintable mt where mt.typename = 'test1'),
           (select id from Maintable mt where mt.typename = 'File4'),
           (select id from Maintable mt where mt.typename = 'Database3')
```

Note:  this works only if there is exactly zero or one entries in the Maintable for any given value.  You might want to use the typeid, but it is not clear from your question.